# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a OfficeVisitBloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a OfficeVisitBloc.
Could not find the correct Provider above this Builder Widget

```dart
    class OfficeVisit extends StatelessWidget {
      const OfficeVisit({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => OfficeVisitBloc(OfficeVisitService(Dio())),
          child: OfficeVisitScreen(),
        );
      }
    }
```

on the officevisitscreen i have widget called customroundedbutton which on click show dialougebox

```
 CustomRoundedButtom(
                    title: "Add Office Visit",
                    onPressed: () {
                 
                      return showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext dialougContext) {
                            return addDialouge();}
```

inside of the dialougebox i have ontap function like this

```dart
    Dialog addDialouge() {
        return Dialog(
            insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Builder(builder: (context) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                },
                child: InkWell(
                          child: const Text("Add"),
                          onTap: () {
                            OfficeVisitRequest officeVisitRequest =
                                OfficeVisitRequest(
                                    place: 'g',
                                    clientId: 1,
                                    appliedTo: 1,
                                    fromDate: '98765',
                                    officeId: ["1"],
                                    officevisitId: 1,
                                    recomendedTo: 1,
                                    toDate: '876',
                                    visitId: 1,
                                    visitTypeId: 1,
                                    remarks: 'fs');
    
      context.read<OfficeVisitBloc>().add(AddVisitClickedEvent(officeVisitRequest: officeVisitRequest));
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

the problem is its not finding the officevisitprovider. How do I pass the office visit provider to the dialougebox.

I tried bloc providinf to the adddialouge widget. But still Iam getting same error.

Comment: Can you wrap `OfficeVisitScreen` with `Builder` and share the feedback

Comment: do i necessarily have to wrap with builder cuz here it onlt needs to listen

Comment: context.read cant access the bloc within the same context we define. I'm just check if this is the case, second can be passing the context value to the dialog method(mostly)

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh help me pass context value to the dialouge method

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

To pass the current instance on showDialog, you can do

```dart
final currentBlocInstance  = context.read<OfficeVisitBloc>()
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext dialougContext) {
     return BlocProvider<OfficeVisitBloc>.value(
        value: currentBlocInstance,
        return addDialouge();
    }
```